# Extracting random effects from a gamlss object

Tags: r, gam, random-effects

I have run a beta regression with random intercepts model using the `gamlss` package in R. The call looks like:

```
uik.max.model <- gamlss(formula = max.opp.vote ~ n_commute + vote_commute + uik_dummy +
                      opp.gd + opp.m + pay + govt_dep + higher_ed + max.opp.n +
                      opp.m*vote_commute + opp.m*n_commute +
                      re(random = ~1|mf),
                    family = BE(),
                    data = poll_df)
```

I want to extract the random effect for each grouping factor (`mf`) from the model object in order to create a predicted probability plot, but I am unable to find where/if they are stored in the object.

Are the random intercepts for each value of the grouping factor available? If so, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To analyze the structure of the fitted object we can use `str(uik.max.model)`. Thus the random effects can be found in `uik.max.model$mu.coefSmo[[1]]$coefficients$random`. Consider this example:

```
library(gamlss)
# creating some data
variable <- as.factor(rep(1:26, 1e3))
levels(variable) <- LETTERS
value <- rbinom(2.6e4, 10, .5)
df1 <- data.frame(variable, value)

# fitting a minimal model
fit <- gamlss(formula = value ~ 1 +
              re(random = ~1|variable),
            data = na.omit(df1))

# analyzing structure of fitted object
str(fit)
# ...

# random effects for each value of "variable"
fit$mu.coefSmo[[1]]$coefficients$random
# $variable
# (Intercept)
# A -1.029350e-07
# B -2.465111e-09
# C  1.326496e-07
# D -1.632303e-08
# E  2.731609e-09
# F -4.403887e-08
# G -2.465111e-09
# H -7.695143e-08
# I  2.698297e-08
# J  4.950209e-08
# K -3.191319e-08
# L  9.627257e-08
# M -4.057439e-08
# N  3.737641e-08
# O -1.285855e-08
# P  1.551687e-07
# Q  1.312505e-08
# R -8.907712e-08
# S -9.394071e-09
# T  2.178625e-08
# U -7.661831e-09
# V -1.978751e-08
# W -8.734488e-08
# X  3.737641e-08
# Y -1.285855e-08
# Z -1.632303e-08
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I was poking around in the wrong places with 'str()'.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Is the total variance in ```value``` attributable to ```variable``` given by ```fit$mu.coefSmo```? I.e. the total random intercept variance not separated out by the levels of ```variable```.

Answer (score 1):

the following might help

```
summary(getSmo(uik.max.model)) # summary
ranef(getSmo(uik.max.model)) # random effect estimates
coef(getSmo(uik.max.model)) # fitted coefficients
intervals(getSmo(uik.max.model)) # Confidence intervals
```

See: Stasinopoulos D. M., Rigby R.A., Heller G., Voudouris V., and De Bastiani F., (2017) Flexible Regression and Smoothing: Using GAMLSS in R, Chapman and Hall/CRC.
Chapter 10

Best regards
Kai